# Unable to sign up a user with react ruby on rails and devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, devise

I am using Rails 6 with React and webpacker with the devise gem.
I make a post request, it hits the correct route, gives me a status 200 OK. There is no error message. But when I check User with `rails console` it shows that there are no new users.

These are my code file for reference. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    
    axios.post('/api/v1/users', inputs)
    .then( res => {
      console.log(res);
    }).catch( res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
  }
```

rails routes

```
                 new_api_v1_user_session GET    /api/v1/users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                   api/v1/users/sessions#new
                     api_v1_user_session POST   /api/v1/users/sign_in(.:format)                                                                   api/v1/users/sessions#create
             destroy_api_v1_user_session DELETE /api/v1/users/sign_out(.:format)                                                                  api/v1/users/sessions#destroy
                new_api_v1_user_password GET    /api/v1/users/password/new(.:format)                                                              api/v1/users/passwords#new
               edit_api_v1_user_password GET    /api/v1/users/password/edit(.:format)                                                             api/v1/users/passwords#edit
                    api_v1_user_password PATCH  /api/v1/users/password(.:format)                                                                  api/v1/users/passwords#update
                                         PUT    /api/v1/users/password(.:format)                                                                  api/v1/users/passwords#update
                                         POST   /api/v1/users/password(.:format)                                                                  api/v1/users/passwords#create
         cancel_api_v1_user_registration GET    /api/v1/users/cancel(.:format)                                                                    api/v1/users/registrations#cancel
            new_api_v1_user_registration GET    /api/v1/users/sign_up(.:format)                                                                   api/v1/users/registrations#new
           edit_api_v1_user_registration GET    /api/v1/users/edit(.:format)                                                                      api/v1/users/registrations#edit
                api_v1_user_registration PATCH  /api/v1/users(.:format)                                                                           api/v1/users/registrations#update
                                         PUT    /api/v1/users(.:format)                                                                           api/v1/users/registrations#update
                                         DELETE /api/v1/users(.:format)                                                                           api/v1/users/registrations#destroy
                                         POST   /api/v1/users(.:format)                                                                           api/v1/users/registrations#create
```

```
module Api 
  module V1 



# frozen_string_literal: true

class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]
  skip_forgery_protection
  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    super
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    super
    debugger
  end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute])
  end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_account_update_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # The path used after sign up.
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    # super(resource)
    
  end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end
end
end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that devise's registration controller does a save without bang, which means it might not raise an error in case of some validations. It might be just that you pass wrong parameters to it and therefore user cannot be created. To debug it you could try to check whats getting into devises controller and what you might be missing. You can achieve that by doing some puts or logging in the devise library code locally (just temporarily of course).

EDIT: Actually it is probably even worse, cause it renders a view with flash messages, so the response will always be 200 OK unless u mess something up in your code in the controller that extends it.

Comment: (byebug) params
#<ActionController::Parameters {"email"=>"wiofjwoeifjwo", "password"=>"fwoiejfwoiefj", "controller"=>"api/v1/users/registrations", "action"=>"create", "registration"=>{"email"=>"wiofjwoeifjwo", "password"=>"fwoiejfwoiefj"}} permitted: false>
-

this is what I get in my params

Comment: @Jonathan Two points:

- I think you are missing password_confirmation parameter
- "registration" top key might be wrong, cause devise works with "user" by default

Comment: `<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"za6Wp96u9wDgbZ8T1SQNHMj2joPih4QTrcKvrE+wAulDk1uZZNVCwktCco/owDzzBhnU9QEj7d5hiT7RtdRI5w==", "user"=><ActionController::Parameters {"email"=>"dsadas@dasdas.dsa", "password"=>"dsadas", "password_confirmation"=>"fdd"} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Register now", "controller"=>"devise/registrations", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>`

Params in my working app using a default devise registration_controller's implementation

Comment: do you know where I could check the top key?

Comment: Your top key is `registration` it is defined either in params object you pass in the js file or in the html form you send through js.